# Number of ways to express a natural number N as a product of K natural numbers where each number is greater than or equal to a natural number M?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-factorization, natural-numbers

I want to know the number of ways to express a natural number N as a product of K natural numbers where each number is greater than or equal to a natural number M? Or a simpler version of the problem can be to determine if it is even possible or not, keeping aside the number of ways of doing it. For example, 4 can be expressed as a product of two natural numbers where each number is greater than or equal to 2, i.e., 4 = 2 x 2, in one way. I tried searching for a solution to this problem but I couldn't find one. I know how to solve problems like x*y*z = 120 but there are no restrictions on what values x, y or z, like the one the above problem has. So what should be done in order to solve the above problem?

Comment: The number $2$ is not greater than $2$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I need to edit the question. It should have been greater than or equal to.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607929/relation-between-divisor-and-prime-factors-of-a-number)

Comment: I don't think that answers my question. Can you give a generalized answer for the one which I asked? I would be very grateful for that.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Tanner your help is highly appreciated.